# Can't get jQuery to fadeIn my images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get these images to fade in at all, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have put `alert("hi")` instead of `$(this).fadeIn()` and the popup is shown. I've tried putting the code at the end, I've tried linking to a a local jQuery script, I've tried just doing the `$("#eTR1").fadeIN()` inside the `$(document).ready()` but that also doesn't work:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $("#eTR1").bind("load", function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
          $("#eTR2").bind("load", function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
          $("#eTR3").bind("load", function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
          $("#eBL1").bind("load", function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
          $("#eBL2").bind("load", function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
          $("#eBL3").bind("load", function() { $(this).fadeIn(); });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside id="eTRRibbons">
      <img id="eTR1" src="res/tr1.png">
      <img id="eTR2" src="res/tr2.png">
      <img id="eTR3" src="res/tr3.png">
    </aside>
    <aside id="eBLRibbons">
      <img id="eBL1" src="res/bl1.png">
      <img id="eBL2" src="res/bl2.png">
      <img id="eBL3" src="res/bl3.png">
    </aside>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
html
{
  height: 100%;
}

body
{
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#eTR1,#eTR2,#eTR3
{
  position: fixed;

  top:   0px;
  right: 0px;

  opacity: 0.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
}

#eBL1,#eBL2,#eBL3
{
  position: fixed;

  bottom: 0px;
  left:   0px;

  opacity: 0.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fadeIn()` works with `display: none;` you should have that set instead of ``opacity: 0` which is not needed.

Comment: As others have pointed it's the css causing the problem. Another proof it works fine with `display: none;`: http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/Fr2C5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't set the opacity in the css. give it a `display: none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/zSzva/

I have also added a 1000ms duration to your fadeIn so you can see the effect in the example.

Answer (score 3):

The `.fadeIn()` works with `display: none;` you should set that in your CSS and not `opacity: 0` which isn't needed.